# How to disable generation of shared objects (.so's) of a third-party library(mysql) which uses cmake

Tags: mysql, c, build, makefile, cmake

I am trying to [build MySql Connector C(6.0.2) from source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-c-building.html) and the default build exports `.so`'s in addition to the static libraries(`.a`'s). I wanted to suppress the generation of the `.so`'s and tried setting [`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to `OFF`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html)(which didn't work). Also tried setting `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to `/dev/null`(which didn't work either). Does any one have any suggestions on how to get around this issue?

I am using cmake-2.8.4(on Ubuntu) and my cmake invocation looks something like this:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"    
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install/root/  
      -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-m64"  
      -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF 
      [-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY:PATH=/dev/null]
```

Comment: Trying to replicate your problem, but I can't even get it to build on ubuntu 10.04 (gcc 4.4.3), cmake 2.8.0

Comment: What errors/problems did you run into? Btw - just added this to the question as well - I am building(or rather attempting to build) mysql-connector-c-6.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Just grep for ADD_LIBRARY in CMakeLists.txt files and comment out the one that adds shared target

Comment: I would prefer not to make changes to the CMakeLists.txt as its a third-party library which we are wrapping around with our build scripts. So ideally it would be nice to be able to control this from outside the library distribution.